# How can a single-shard Redis Cluster give CROSSSLOT errors?

Tags: redis, sharding, redis-cluster

I don't understand how a Redis Cluster with only one shard can result in a CROSSSLOT error. According to the documentation, this error occurs when you issue a command that affects multiple keys that do not all reside within the same hash slot (i.e. node in a sharded environment). Given that a single shard has only one slot; 0-16383 - and hence all the data - how can this happen?

In my case I have a single shard with one read-replica (slave).

I circumvented the issue by using the hash tags as explained here: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec - however this does not answer the question.

This is the output from CLUSTER NODES:

```
e51c5f84e60116be3cb9d6734fc0c4deb1fde4c4 172.31.6.149:6379@1122 slave c07ed67b7df1a9d4475702c944a43ad38c6954ba 0 1531143884198 1 connected
c07ed67b7df1a9d4475702c944a43ad38c6954ba 172.31.21.122:6379@1122 myself,master - 0 0 1 connected 0-16383
```

I can reproduce the error like this:

```
telnet 172.31.21.122 6379

SETEX redis-test-1 3600 whatever
+OK
SETEX redis-test-2 3600 whatever
+OK

KEYS redis-test*
*2
$12
redis-test-2
$12
redis-test-1

DEL redis-test-1 redis-test-2
-CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot
```

Answer (score 1):

This confused me too. The [Redis code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/f3980bb9fd167420acda96419d8db991cc85d1e1/src/cluster.c#L5493) requires that the keys hash to the same slot (not to the same node) and I don't understand why that is, given the [cluster specification](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#implemented-subset) says the following (emphasis mine):

> Redis Cluster implements all the single key commands available in the non-distributed version of Redis. Commands performing complex multi-key operations like Set type unions or intersections are implemented as well as long as the keys all belong to the **same node**.

I opened an issue on GH: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/5118

Comment: I think the reason we cannot do multi-key operations on keys that do not belong to the same slot *when in cluster mode* is because you cannot *be sure* that the keys reside within the same node. This is of course always the case when using a single shard, but a cluster is not meant to be operated with just a single shard. You may suddenly split it into two and then you'll have trouble if you do multi-key operations on keys that are not in the same node anymore.

Comment: @nickdnk - that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

> Given that a single shard has only one slot; 0-16383

That single shard holds **all** 16384 slots, each of them is "single"...

Comment: So it would seem. I was confused by the difference between slots and shards.